PrimeVue components show on screen but i cant use them
I'm trying to get PrimeVue to work on my Laravel, Vite and Vue.js application but i cant seem to be able to interact with most of the components. I'm not sure if im missing a JS import or something
Only the dropdown works
app.js (same as main.js)
import "./bootstrap";
import router from "./router";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
import 'primevue/resources/themes/mdc-light-indigo/theme.css'

import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App)

export function checkISMobile(){
    if(screen.width <= 760){
        return true;
    }
    return false
}

app.use(router)
app.use(PrimeVue, {
    ripple: true,
    inputStyle: "filled"
})

app.mount('#app')

app.css

@layer tailwind-base, primevue, tailwind-utilities;



@layer tailwind-utilities {
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
}

I thought it was beacuse i was using tailwind so i tried going unstyled and setting up to follow tailwind but that didnt work either
--Edit


<template>
    <h1>Search Page</h1>
    <Dropdown v-model="selectedCity" :options="cities" optionLabel="name" placeholder="Select a City" class="w-full md:w-14rem" />
<br><br>
<h4>FloatLabel</h4>
    <FloatLabel>
    <InputText id="username" v-model="username" />
    <label for="username">Username</label>
</FloatLabel>

    <Knob v-model="value" />
    <InputSwitch v-model="checked" />

    <Rating v-model="value" />

</template>



What i mean by 'Able to Interact' is For example the FloatLabel should have the label inside the input box and then when you click on it then it moves ontop of it, and the InputSwitch doesn't change when clicked

Please, provide a way to reproduce. What you're doing is the way it's used. Did you try to not use Tailwind at all? "able to interact" - in which way exactly? The screenshot obviously doesn't represent the interaction part

I tried using unstyled and tailwind by following the guide on PrimeVue and got that working but it didn't help the problem I was having

So you didn't try to not use tailwind at all? I'd suggest to try this first. Currently it looks like it's the problem here, but it needs to be isolated in order for your question to be correctly addressed. Notice that the recommended approach regarding tailwind differs from what you're trying https://tailwind.primevue.org/overview
